# Set image settings for each individual File Output Node, in the Python API

Tags: python, scripting, node-editor, image, saving

In one scene I have two seperate FileOutputNodes and I want different color depths and file formats for each.

In the Blender GUI this is simple. You can press a FileOutputNode, then press *N*. Then the *Properties* panel shows and you can change the image settings for each node.

How do I do the same through the python API? I tried creating seperate *bpy.types.ImageFormatSettings* for each node, but unfortunately that attribute is read-only.

---

*In particular, I want one node to have Open_EXR, 16-bit RGB; the other PNG 8-bit RGB.*

*I know I can create two seperate scenes and set the image settings for each scene, but I'd rather have one scene (because that's less code).*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually set the settings for each individual node.

Create your node:

```
file_output_node = tree.nodes.new('CompositorNodeOutputFile')
```

Then you can set your settings for this node by going into the *format* attribute. For example:

```
file_output_node.format.file_format = "PNG" # default is "PNG"
file_output_node.format.color_mode = "RGB"  # default is "BW"
file_output_node.format.color_depth = "16"  # default is 8
file_output_node.format.compression = 0     # default is 15
```